# Large difference between the atomic sizes of uranium and thorium

Tags: atomic-physics, elements

According to Villars and Daams [Journal of Alloys and Compounds, 197 (1993) 177] the atomic volume of U is $2.073\times10^{-2}\,\mathrm{nm^3}$, whereas that of Th is much larger, $3.295\times 10^{-2}\,\mathrm{nm^3}$.

The external electronic configurations of these atoms are:

Th: $[\text{Rn]} 6d^2 7s^2$

U: $[\text{Rn}] 5f^3 6d^1 7s^2$

What's the origin of this large difference?

Why, then, are their ionic sizes (for example the sizes of Th$^{4+}$ and U$^{4+}$) quite similar?

Comment: The title of the question implies there is a different in atomic sizes of Uranium, but the body of the question asks about U vs Th, which are different elements.

Comment: Given how the entire concept of atomic sizes is somewhat nebulous, I'd question the consistency of the data before embarking on a journey to explain it.

Answer (score 10):

This is due to the *Actinide contraction*, analogous to the [Lanthanide contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanthanide_contraction):

> The effect results from poor shielding of nuclear charge (nuclear
> attractive force on electrons) by 5f electrons; the 6s electrons are
> drawn towards the nucleus, thus resulting in a smaller atomic radius.

For the Actinide contraction, instead read: "[...] *by 4f electrons; the 7s electrons are drawn towards the nucleus,* [...]".

Comment: sorry, but I cannot see how this explain the huge difference between the atomic size of U and Th. Th and U stand below Ce and Nd in the periodic table, but the atomic volume of Ce and Nd are quite similar, whereas that of U is about 60% that of Th. According to Cotton* "The 5f orbitals are not shielded by the filled 6s and 6p subshells as the 4f orbitals of the lanthanides are (by the corresponding 5s and 5p subshells)", but in elemental Th no 5f electrons are present, whereas in U there are 3 5f electrons. On this basis, I would expect larger volume for U. *[Lanthanide and Actinide Chemistry]

Comment: Firstly, the 'huge difference' looks a lot bigger than when you look at *atomic radii* rather than volumes (volume requires cubing). Wiki gives empirical data of radius of 180 pm and 175 pm for Th and U resp. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radii_of_the_elements_(data_page) Secondly, I don't know how 'Cotton' (who?) concludes what he concludes.

Comment: If you look at the Lanthanides, then the contraction of radii isn't spectacular either. Really what you find is no expansion, which in itself is unexpected and explained by the deeper $f$ orbital.

Comment: It seems to me that data reported by Wiki are rather old [Slater (1964)]. I refer to data of Villars and Daams (1993) where, as I wrote the difference in the atomic volumes (not radii) between U and Th are very large. Even if Th and U crystallize with different structures, they have the same coordination number (12). In U the U-U bond distance is 0.275 nm, whereas in Th the Th-Th bond distance is much larger 0.360 nm. Why this difference? This huge difference is not observed for Ce and Pr (where 0.333 and 0.363 bond distances are measured).

Comment: PS: "... 'Cotton' (who?)". It should be this: https://www.birmingham.ac.uk/staff/profiles/chemistry/cotton-simon.aspx

Comment: Although it's utterly pointless to squabble about data neither of us generated themselves, I believe the difference between U and Th you refer to isn't supported by mainstream literature and must be considered anomalous.  It could be useful to pose your question in Chem.SE, just an idea... All the best.

Comment: @gryphys - in $\alpha$U there are several U-U bond distances. See https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4306144 - "Imagining the central uranium atom at the center of a sphere, two close contacts lie in the polar directions (±a, respectively) and two lie on the equator at an angular separation of 128.2°. The coordination polyhedron is roughly a trigonal bipyramid with one base atom missing. The disparity between the four short and the eight long contacts has suggested a stronger, more "covalent" character for the former and a weaker, more "metallic" character for the latter"